# Looking for the best solution

Tags: performance, scala, optimization, review

Consider this list composed of objects which are instances of case classes:

```
A, B, Opt(A),C, Opt(D), F, Opt(C), G, Opt(H)
```

I wan to normalize this list to get this result:

```
A, B, C, Opt(D), F, G, Opt(H)
```

As you see, if there are elements `A` and `Opt(A)` I replace them with just `A` or said other way, I have to remove `OPT(A)` element.

I would like:

- most optimal solution in the mean of performance
- shortest solution

Comment: So equal elements can appear only once? And the list is sorted alphabetically? Why aren't you using a Set?

Comment: List don't have to be sorted. As I said: if there are found both elements Opt(A) and just A, they are replaced with just A. I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: What do you mean with `Opt`? Do you mean Option?

Comment: Exactly... I forgot to mention it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a little more concise, as filtering is what you want ;-):

```
scala> List(1,2,3,Some(4),5,Some(5))
res0: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, Some(4), 5, Some(5))

scala> res0.filter {
     | case Some(x) => !res0.contains(x)
     | case _ => true
     | }
res1: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, Some(4), 5)
```

edit: For large collections it might be good to use a `toSet` or directly use a `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient solution, but certainly a simple one.

```
scala> case class Opt[A](a: A)
defined class Opt

scala> val xs = List(1, 2, Opt(1), 3, Opt(4), 6, Opt(3), 7, Opt(8))
xs: List[Any] = List(1, 2, Opt(1), 3, Opt(4), 6, Opt(3), 7, Opt(8))

scala> xs flatMap {
     |   case o @ Opt(x) => if(xs contains x) None else Some(o)
     |   case x => Some(x)
     | }
res5: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, Opt(4), 6, 7, Opt(8))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about order then efficiency leads you to use a Set:

```
xs.foldLeft(Set.empty[Any])({ case (set, x) => x match {
  case Some(y) => if (set contains y) set else set + x
  case y => if (set contains Some(y)) set - Some(y) + y else set + y
}}).toList
```

Alternatively:

```
val (opts, ints) = xs.toSet.partition(_.isInstanceOf[Option[_]])
opts -- (ints map (Option(_))) ++ ints toList
```

Comment: Your solution will not work with a list like `List(Some(1),1)`.

Comment: @drexin It produces `List(1)`, which if I read the question properly is the correct answer...?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I used `:paste` in the repl, which returned the assignment to `xs`. But are you sure that creating instances of `Option` for every value in the list, then do a lookup and always create new immutable instances of `Set` is more efficient, than a `filter` with a lookup an a `List`? I think the `filter` on `xs.toSet` will be better.

Comment: @drexin Adding or removing from an immutable Set is very cheap, because most of the set is re-used. Traversing a List with `contains` is expensive (O(n) where n is length). If you convert to a Set first, I don't know how this would compare to `filter` - I would guess it would be in the same ballpark